# QGIS print composer does not export high res details from Spatialite layer

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, print-composer, qgis-print-layouts

I downloaded OSM.pbf data from Geofabrik, and I followed https://anitagraser.com/2014/05/31/a-guide-to-googlemaps-like-maps-with-osm-in-qgis/ 
this example to import pbf file to SpatiaLite layer for my map. (QGIS 3.4.2) Now I have google style OSM data as Spatialite layer.

I need to print out 60km x 60km zone in high quality, so I zoomed out map from canvas to fit my target area in the screen, and moved to print composer (or print layout). Then I set the layout size, set north/south/west/est extents, then export image to have my target resolution (16000px).

However, after I checked high resolution png file, all names, roads and rivers are magnified, and all details & minor roads are ignored. It seems that print composer exported the exact same image of canvas, which I zoomed out to fit 60km x 60km target region in screen.

This never happened to me When I printed maps from Quickmap service plug-in. Using maps from the plug-in, even though map was zoomed out, print composer exported high quality map with details.

How can I export high quality details from Spatialite layer using print composer?

Comment: What do you mean 16000 px target resolution? It seems too high.

Comment: I suppose that in Anita's styles there are scale rules to avoid too many details in lower scales. Have a look to the scale rules first.